# Функция, которая будет выполняться раз в неделю

Tags: php

Есть функция,

```
function SetCount() {
        $today = date("w");
        if($today == 1) {
            $count = 3500;
            $random = rand(2,5);
            $counter = $count + $random;
        }
        echo $counter;
    }
    SetCount();
```

которая должна выполняться раз в неделю(например, по понедельникам) и увеличивать `$count` на рандомное число из диапазона от 2 до 5. По итогу должно получиться следующее:

- выполняться единоразово раз в неделю
- `$count`должен увеличиваться на рандомное число в диапазоне от 2 до 5
- при последующем запуске функции значение из рандома должно прибавиться к текущему значению, а не к `$count = 3500`

Просьба без использования `cron`

Comment: а кто будет запускать вашу функцию? попробуйте описать задачу, а не решение.

Comment: при загрузке страницы функция будет выполняться. Может натолкнете на мысль?)

Comment: Запускаете cron раз в неделю и ни каких проблем :)

Comment: @MikhailVaysman дух святой, очевидно.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman При загрузке страницы должна быть проверка на дату(если прошла неделя, то будет запускаться функция, в которой счетчик $count будет прибавлять постоянно число, взятое из рандома в диапазоне от 2 до 5)

Comment: `проверка на дату(если прошла неделя)` подразумевает, что у страницы будет какое-то состояние, сохраняемое между загрузками. Поскольку держать запущенный процесс PHP неделю нерационально, вам понадобится БД или что-то ещё. Но это всё будут ужасные костыли по сравнению с cron. Чем он вам не угодил-то? Если не знаете, как использовать, так проще научиться.

Comment: Сама идея была в том, чтобы вытянуть дату через strtotime, затем прибавить к ней 604800 сек(неделя) и сравнивать с текущей, в случае, если дата была бы равной дате+неделя, то прибавлять к $count значение и снова брать дату+неделя

Comment: Я понял, тогда буду через cron. Думал, что будет проще выполнить процедурно без использования чего либо